# daily score based on last 30 days average

Tags: scoring-algorithm

I'm creating an application that measures EV charging poles usage to see how many KWH they use in this area. Based on measurements the average for the last 30 days is 94, and daily values range from 140 to 50. I would like to get a daily score (1-10) based on the score of that day and the average from the last 30 days.

I don't really have any affinity with math, how would one go to calculate this score?

thanks in advance ^^

Comment: Can you just calculate the average? Or is there something wrong with using the plain old average?

Comment: The average itself is not enough; you need some measure for the spread. One easy way to do this is taking the interval [50,140], dividing it up in 10 equal sized subintervals and labeling the first 'One', the second 'Two' ...